# Unable to create document in mongoid with field type array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid4

Following is my model which has a field with type array

```
class User::Log::Presentation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :fields, type: Array, default: []
end
```

When I try creating a document, it throws following error.

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

I am totally lost with this. Couldnt find any answer is other questions. Please help.

Comment: can you show how you are saving the values?

Comment: p = User::Log::Presentation.new ; p.fields = ["date", "log"] throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following change and started working.

```
field :fields, type: Array, default: []
```

to

```
field :columns, type: Array, default: []
```